# how to use switch case to take a string parameter?

Tags: string, switch-statement

How do I take string input as a switch case parameter?  I am able to do it with an `int` but not string.

The below code would be working if I was using an `int` input, but if I change to string it won't work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
class MissionPlan //start of MissionPlan class
{
    public:
    MissionPlan();
    float computeCivIndex(string,int,int,float,float);
}; //end of MissionPlan class

LocationData::LocationData()
{
    switch(sunType)
    {
        case "Type A": //compute 
                      break;
        case "Type B": //compute
                       break;
         //and many more case..
        default: break;
    }
}
int main()
{

    for(;;)
    {
    MissionPlan plan;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I haven't touched C++ in over 12 years, but I'm pretty sure you can't.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use a switch statement on a string in C++, sorry.  You're best bet here is to use an enum.  If you don't want to use an enum, then your only other option would be to do a bunch of if elses that check the strings for equality.

Answer (score 0):

C/C++ doesn't support `switch` statements with strings. Use `if-else-if` instead:

```
if (sunType.compare("Type A") == 0) {
     //compute
} else if (sunType.compare("Type B") == 0) {
     // compute
} else {
     // default
}
```

Comment: cant i use if(sunType=="Type A") { //compute} ??

Comment: I do not develop in C++ that much, but I do not see a overloaded `==` operator for the `std::string` class.